# tsconfig outfile with systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs, tsconfig

I have the exact same issue as here:
[SystemJS: loading build file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715307/systemjs-loading-build-file/39739892)

however I am getting a network error because I assume systemjs is trying to download main from the web but it does not exist on the web which is right because it is inside the buildjs file which has already been downloade dinto the browser

how do I make systemjs look inside the already downloaded buildjs file only and not try and download it over the network?

Comment: First guess: SystemJS will take the module from the bundle only if module name which is assigned in the bundle matches exactly module name in the import statement in source code.

Comment: yes this is correct and I opened it up and it only said "main" not something like "app/main"

Comment: System.register("main", ['@angular/platform-browser-dynamic', "app.module"], function(exports_20, context_20) {

Comment: could it be something like angular/platform-browser-dynamic is not being bundled into the buidljs? only the app specific code is being bundled?  so maybe main fails because of a dependency? just a guess, but I have the angular2 in my systemjs.config.js

Comment: There are so many possible reasons for things to go wrong that I can go on guessing forever. Next guess: is there something that maps `main` to something else in SystemJS configuration? BTW if something is included in the buidjs file or not is determined by the way you make that file - if you do it with typescript then angular libraries like platform-browser-dynamic definitely are not there.

Comment: yes I did it with tsconfig outfile paramater

Comment: ok seems like it might be related to the whole moduleid issue which I am using in my components, the main error is deceptive

Answer (score 0):

so it seems that the error message is not so helpful and it might be something deeper.  I put an alert box in the code of my main module and it popped up so this told me the main was executing.  I turned out if was related to moduleId: module.id / __moduleName issue.  If your module execution fails I guess it tried to download it as a backup strategy.  anyways I fixed my coding issue and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use outfile and systemjs at the same time, as they serve the same purpose. Build your ts files separately and use systemjs builder instead.